# Como modificar la URL de mi app en google play

Tags: url, app, google-play

Me gustaria tener una url de mi app mas corta, que esta en google play, pero no se como cambiarla, alguien sabe como se puede modificar la URL.
gracias

Comment: Te sugiero añadir más información a tu pregunta, ¿te refieres a la url de Google Play o solo deseas una url para compartir?. Es importante revises [ask] para crear preguntas.

Comment: Creo que esta bien planteada, "la url de mi app en google play".  Gracias

Answer (score -1, accepted):

La url de la aplicación se crea en base a cómo está registrada la app al momento de programarla, la cual sería

com.{nombre de la empresa que la creó}.{nombre de la app}

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rovio.angrybirds

Esto lo puedes ver en el archivo AndroidManifest.xml

Si necesitas hacer más pequeño el link para por ejemplo incluirlo dentro de un SMS o para que la gente lo digite más rápido puedes usar algún servicio de acortamiento de links como https://bitly.com/